# Virtual Directory pointing to UNC share

Tags: iis-6, virtual-directory

I have an app that uploads documents to the server through the standard

When sent my application to the production server, I found out that they had the server load balanced.  My solution to this was to place the upload directory into a network share and then create a virtual directory pointing to the share.

I have set permissions on the share and the file itself, but I keep getting "access denied" whenever I try to upload a document.

Where could I be missing permissions?  Is it possible that IUSR needs to have access to the share?

Thanks.

Comment: For anyone reading this, this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/617819/401-1-error-when-accessing-virtual-directory-pointing-to-network-share/29776881#29776881

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI,

The answer to this solution for me was to setup temporary impersonation with a user account that had access to the share, the folder and the virtual directory.

Here's a link to the code that worked for me:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158#4

Answer (score 1):

I hope your site use anonymous access. Otherwise you will have a painful experience.

If it is so ( anonymous acess), then: The IUSR is a local user on the production servers and not a domain user. So it don't have access the the share. You will have to change that  to a domain user ( in the site configuration and not on the application pool). And make sure that the application pool run on a network service ( this is the default ) and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that whatever your ASP.Net process is running as does not have access to the share.

So chances are you need to set up an IIS6 application pool to run as a domain user and have that domain user have access rights to the file share.

Don't forget to aspnet_regiis -ga {domainuser} so that the domain user can actually run asp.net applications.