# Website stops working after IIS deployment folder(physical path for virtual directory) is shared

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

I came to an annoying problem. A website deployed on IIS7.5 on windows 7 was working fine. I shared the folder(physical path for the virtual directory of a website) to a colleague and website stopped working.

It's giving the error: `can't establish the connection to the server`.

Later I removed sharing but still, the website can be browsed & giving the same error.

All other websites hosted on IIS are working fine.

Any leads on this will be helpful?

Comment: Did you see http://stackoverflow.com/q/387369/822637?

Comment: @sq33G, seen it, its different issue altogther. My issue is similar to http://serverfault.com/questions/330707/iis7-web-site-not-working-properly-after-file-sharing-on-wwwroot but solution doesn't worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

What I found is that By enable sharing it also revokes permission  for "**Users**" i.e serverName\Users.
All you got to do is add "Users" and it worked fine. 
Hope it would be usefull

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.  What I found is when you enable sharing on a directory it removes access permissions for the Appl Pool user and causes a failure.  I had to manually add the --SERVER_NAME--\IIS_IUSRS user with full permissions to the directory that was shared.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. it works most of the time. But in my case, i have tried that too, but doesn't work. Ultimately I have to map virtual directory to new folder.

Comment: That fixed it for me.What was really annoying was that it only gave a 500 error an no web.config change could make it give detailed errors since IIS couldn't read the web.config.